# Need to empty the int values which are in textboxes

Tags: c#, mysql

i have three text boxes for telephone number mobile number and for age;
i enter the details there and insert them in to the database. after insert how can i make textboxes cleared. it won't allow me to do so coz insert method is like this

```
public void insert(int mobile,int telephone,int age)
{
  try
        {
            MySqlConnection asp= new MySqlConnection(conString);
            asp.Open();




            string insertString = "insert into users(mob,tele,age) values('"+mobile+"','"+telephone+"','"+age+"')

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertString,asp);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        MessageBox.Show("New user added succesfully","Information");       

 //afteer this how to empty the three textboxes
 // ihave used these three as integers in database         

}
```

calling method is

```
insert(int.parse(textbox1text),int.parse(textbox2.text),int.parse(textbox3.text))
```

Comment: `textBox1.Clear();textBox2.Clear();textBox3.Clear();`
right after this line `insert(mobile,telephone,age);` and use command parameters.

Comment: I would suggest don't use int for phone numbers.

Comment: Yes thanks it has to be done in the place where we call the insert method. ha haa i think im depressed. can't event think about this type of  a thing. thanks alot manoj

Comment: Jurion You suggest to use string instead of ints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [TextBox.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to clear the contents of the `TextBox` after the `Insert()`statement

Try This:

```
insert(int.parse(textbox1.Text),int.parse(textbox2.Text),int.parse(textbox3.Text));
textBox1.Clear();
textBox2.Clear();
textBox3.Clear();
```

Comment: nope cant do so. i have insert method defined in a separate class so cant access them

Answer (score 0):

After Calling Insert method Just use this

```
insert(int.parse(textbox1text),int.parse(textbox2.text),int.parse(textbox3.text));
textBox1.Text =String.Empty;
textBox2.Text =String.Empty;
textBox3.Text =String.Empty;
```

(or)

```
insert(int.parse(textbox1text),int.parse(textbox2.text),int.parse(textbox3.text));
textBox1.Text ="";
textBox2.Text ="";
textBox3.Text ="";
```